# AutoMapper Value supplied is of wrong type

Tags: c#, type-conversion, automapper

I'm trying to map a type `UserProfileEditorViewModel` to a type `UserProfile` as follows:

```
public ActionResult Edit(UserProfileEditorViewModel userProfileViewModel)
        {
            UserProfile user = _getUserByIdQuery.Invoke(SessionData.UserId);

            Mapper.Map(userProfileViewModel, user);
```

Which currently throws this error:

> Value supplied is of type System.String but expected
>   MyNamespace.Web.Models.UserProfileEditorViewModel.

On the line `Mapper.Map(userProfileViewModel, user);`.

My mapping configuration for this looks like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserProfileEditorViewModel, UserProfile>()
                .ForMember(
                   dto => dto.Tags, 
                   opt => opt.ResolveUsing<TagNameStringToTagCollectionResolver>());
```

where `TagNameStringToTagCollectionResolver` looks like:

```
 protected override IEnumerable<Tag> ResolveCore(string source)
        {
            return _getTagsByNamesQuery.Invoke(source.Split(','));
        }
```

Any ideas why it's throwning that exception? I'm new to Automapper and a bit stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that `TagNameStringToTagCollectionResolver` needs to accept a parameter of type `UserProfileEditorViewModel` on its `ResolveCore` method.

The error message being displayed indicates that something somewhere in the mapping is supplying a value of type `string` in it's method signature when it needs to be supplying a value of type `UserProfileEditorViewModel`.

It's a bit of a confusing exception given the wording but this is how I solved the problem non the less.

```
protected override IEnumerable<Tag> ResolveCore(UserProfileEditorViewModel source)
        {
            return _getTagsByNamesQuery.Invoke(source.Tags.Split(','));
        }
```